# Docker container with NodeJs is self shutting down on Window

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a bit of a problem with the NodeJS that is shutting down after a few seconds from the moment the run command had started to execute.

For a start, I had created a react project by running the command `create-react-app <my_project_name>`. After this, in the project folder, I had created a docker file named Dockerfile.dev. that looks like:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

And compiled it with the command `docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t emy .`
The build was a success, but when it had come to run it with the command `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 emy` . The container is self shutting down after a few seconds.

This is the structure of the generated project:
[image]

And the output of the docker running command for **git bash terminal**:
[image]
And for the **window terminal**:
[image]

The container **exit code** is 0. So it's normal...

**Steps to reproduce the problem**:

1) Install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

2) Install [react project generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app).

3) Create a project by running the command `create-react-app <my_project_name>` in the window terminal.

4) Step into the newly created project, with `cd <my_project_name>`

5) Create Docker file with the content that you can find above.

6) Build the container by running the command `docker build -t emy .`

7) Now let's reproduce the problem by running the container with the command `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 emy`

8) Wait 5 seconds (max) and you should have the same problem us me.

Comment: Is the container producing any interesting log messages?  Is it exiting with success or failure?  How can I use the image files you've attached here to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I had updated my question details to include the information that you had requested. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add "it" argument to the docker run command. For **git bash terminal**:
[image]

and for **window terminal**:
[image]
Hope this will help others